# Extract a file name from the full file path

Tags: vbscript

In VBScript how to separate Test1_QTP folder name alone from the below path. I need to extract "Test1_QTP" string into a variable.

```
C:\TeamTask\Automation\Daily\EB\20140508\Test1_QTP
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim strMyPath, strFileName
strMyPath = "C:\TeamTask\Automation\Daily\EB\20140508\Test1_QTP"
strFileName = Mid(strMyPath, InStrRev(strMyPath, "\") + 1)
```

Answer (score 6):

If the specified folder exists, you can use the [`FileSystemObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) object instead of string manipulations:

```
strPath = "C:\TeamTask\Automation\Daily\EB\20140508\Test1_QTP"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
strName = fso.GetFolder(strPath).Name
```